# Polynomial transformation of matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, transformation

Perhaps a trivial question, but as output of R package ptw I have a set of polynomial coefficients (stored in slot warp.coef) which specify a polynomial transformation of the time axis. E.g.

```
warpcoeff=c(-0.0001357075,1.000147,7.281139e-09,-8.870294e-13,-2.60201e-16,1.671129e-20)
```

for a 5th order polynomial transformation (the order can vary though).
I now have a matrix `x` with time values to which I would like to apply this polynomial transformation (to all elements in turn). What is the easiest and fastest way to do this?
(ideally it should both work for when x is a vector or a matrix)

cheers,
Tom

Comment: Is the first element the coefficient of x^5, 2nd x^4 and so on...?

Comment: first element is constant, then x, then x^2, etc

Comment: So, you'd want each element of the matrix to be considered `x` to which this transformation should be applied, right?

Comment: yes that's right! :-)

Comment: You said you had them in a slot. For a model object? Have you tried `predict` on your model? Or is the problem applying this to a matrix?

Comment: I may be missing something, but if you have a vector `x` and an equation, just do `newx <- a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + ...`

Comment: well what I don't know is perhaps quite trivial - but it's how to go from the coefficients (a vector which can be of arbitrary length corresponding to a particular polynomial order) to an equation I can use to predict new values, ie I could do newx <- warpcoeff[1]+warpcoeff[2]*x+..., but I don't quite know how to do it if vector warpcoeff can be of arbitrary length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the transformation to just apply on each element of your matrix, then, you could construct a recursive function like this:

```
my_fn <- function(x, w) {
    idx <- length(w)
    if (idx == 0) return(0)
    o <- x^(idx-1) * w[idx] + my_fn(x, head(w, -1))
}

x <- matrix(1:15, ncol=3)
o <- my_fn(x, warpcoeff)

> o
#          [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 1.000011  6.000747 11.00148
# [2,] 2.000158  7.000894 12.00163
# [3,] 3.000305  8.001041 13.00178
# [4,] 4.000452  9.001188 14.00192
# [5,] 5.000599 10.001335 15.00207
```

Alternatively, you could use `Reduce` as:

```
Reduce('+', lapply(0:5, function(idx) x^idx * w[idx+1]))
```